# Matplotlib 3D Surface missing 1 required positional argument: 'Z'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to make 3D surface just like in this example: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66367/display-a-georeferenced-dem-surface-in-3d-matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import *
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
from matplotlib import cm

data = np.random.random((20, 2))
z = np.random.randint(5, 30, 20)
x = data.T[0]
y = data.T[-1]
xi = np.linspace(min(x), max(x))
yi = np.linspace(min(x), max(y))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

Z = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, c=z)
Axes3D.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=1, antialiased=True)
plt.show()
```

I think my code is similar as the example, but it doesn't
work. I got this error

> TypeError: plot_surface() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Z'

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use your 3D axis object to plot. To do so, replace

```
Axes3D.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=1, antialiased=True)
```

by

```
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=1, antialiased=True)
```

I am not even sure why you were in the first place using `Axes3D.plot_surface` even after having defining an object `ax` of kind `Axes3D`.

P.S: I (using matplotlib version `2.2.2`) also got a warning

> The griddata function was deprecated in version 2.2.

[image]

Comment: Per the official documentation (https://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#getting-started), using Axes3D is the recommended way of performing 3D plots.

Comment: @AmphotericLewisAcid : It says "For those using older versions of matplotlib, change ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d') to ax = Axes3D(fig).". Here I think  OP is already using `2+` version